# Rich JavaScript DHTML menus

Tags: javascript, menu

Can someone suggest a JS menu script that would be able to support menus such as those that are made here http://www.brightstarr.com/US/Pages/Default.aspx ?

I've been searching the web but can't quite phrase it correctly so I always end up either on Superfish or some other plain dropdown menu?

What I need is support for big menus, broken apart in sections with optional images support (image per menu link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Soh Tanaka's Mega Menu](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/) is the classic example of setting up this style of menu.  I'd go so far as to say it's the gold standard for mega menu scripts.  After building the tutorial, it should be easy to do anything you want inside the divs for each relevant area.

The best part about using a pre-done solution with a tutorial like this is that not only do you get to learn, but it's also been well tested and revised.

If the above example is a little too strict with `<li>` elements, you might [try this tutorial from SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/)

Comment: I guess "Mega" was the word I was looking for, that's why I didn't find anything. I guess it's like that with todays search engines, one word making all the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The particular page doesn't seem to use JS for their menu at all - just CSS leveraging the `:hover` pseudoclass. Found a tutorial [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu). The bottom line is that you write all the markup your dropdows require, season them with CSS styles to taste (and position!), and finally put the `:hover` in place in your stylesheet to just make the submenus appear when you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

I would just search for plugins for your favorite javascript framework. There are probably about 1000 if you search "jquery drop down menu plugin". The big sizes and adding of images is pretty standard in the ones I've used as well since they are just divs. I don't know if you are used to working with jquery but I am sure there are plugins for all the other big frameworks out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the menu for the BrightStarr Site.  It doesn't use JS at all, I tried lots of techniques before deciding on this and I choose this for the simple reason that it performs much better on mobile devices than any other JS solution I've come across.